# when to use detached criteria in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

when to use detached criteria? and what is the advantage we get by using detached criterias instead of normal criteria?

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Some.class);


DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Some.class);
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/DetachedCriteria.html)

> Some applications need to create criteria queries in "detached mode",
>   where the Hibernate session is not available. This class may be
>   instantiated anywhere, and then a Criteria may be obtained by passing
>   a session to `getExecutableCriteria()`. All methods have the same
>   semantics and behavior as the corresponding methods of the Criteria
>   interface.

Answer (score 11):

'Detached from session object' 
Detached Criteria may be used in two scenarios:

1. Building criteria query with no session object: 
    Session only requires during executing the query/submitting the query to database, not while building the query.

   Ex:

   ```
       DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Department.class);
       detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("DEPTID", 1));
       ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
       projectionList.add(Projections.property("DEPTID"));
       detachedCriteria.setProjection(projectionList);

      //Add more
       .............................
   ```

   In the above code do you find any necessity of having session object for building such a criteria query? absolutely NO.
2. Building same criteria query for multiple times:
    Build it once irrespective of the session object, and can be used whenever/wherever you want.

Finally when session object is available, use the above query with session as follows:

```
detachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(session).list();
```