# JPA createQuery working but createCriteria not working session is closed error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, createcriteria, createquery

I am trying to use Criteria API from Hibernate by getting hibernate session from EntityManager as following

```
public org.hibernate.Criteria getCriteria() {
    HibernateEntityManager hem = em.unwrap(HibernateEntityManager.class);
    org.hibernate.Session session = hem.getSession();
    return session.createCriteria(getEntityBeanType());
}
```

In createCriteria return I am getting "session is closed error".

From the same point of code where I call getCriteria if I call createQuery method as

```
getEntityManager().createQuery(".....");
```

It is working fine and I can do select on database.

I want to use Hibernate Criteria API becuase I am comfortable with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure if your session is open before you create criteria

```
public org.hibernate.Criteria getCriteria() {

    HibernateEntityManager hem = em.unwrap(HibernateEntityManager.class);
    org.hibernate.Session session = hem.getSession();

 if(session.isOpen())
{
return session.createCriteria(getEntityBeanType())
}

    return null;
}
```

Check your log for more information and share the same here and it will be helpful for us to debug...

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem, but the session is initially open when I call createCriteria(). Somehow, the createCriteria() call closes the session. I can see that happen in the debugger, but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

The point here is that Criteria object exists only when Session object is open, if the Session object has been closed Criteria object won't work, there is a class named `DetachedCriteria` that allows the developer create Criteria queries outside of Session object then attach them to it and be able to run. Read more about Detached [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925948/when-to-use-detached-criteria-in-hibernate)

Detached criteria is very good alternate when the hibernate session is not present

You can use something like this.

```
//Not required a session open
DetachedCriteria query = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Employee.class);
query.add(Property.forName("name").eq("Som"));

//Here we open the session
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

//Then we associate the criteria query with the session and run it
employeeList = query.getExecutableCriteria(session).list();
Iterator it = employeeList.iterator();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been seeing the same problem. It comes out of the improper use of the @Transactional annotation. Here's what I was doing:

```
doStuff(String[] ids) {
  Criteria criteria = dao.createCriteria(Widget.class); // Session still open here.
  criteria.add(Restrictions.in("widgetId", ids)); // This closed the session!
  ...
}
```

It turns out that my dao class was annotated with the `@Transactional` annotation. So as soon as I tried to do something with my Criteria, it first closed the transaction, which closes the session. The solution was get rid of the dao's `createCriteria()` method and to add a method to the dao that does all the work with that uses the Criteria instance.

```
doStuff(String[] ids) {
  List<Widget> = dao.getWidgetsFromIds(ids); // Do everything inside the transaction
  ...
}
----
// This is in the DAO:
public List<Widget> getWidgetsFromIds(String[] ids) {
  Criteria criteria = dao.createCriteria(Widget.class); // Session is open here.
  criteria.add(Restrictions.in("widgetId", ids)); // Session still open
  ...
}
```

The way I've structured my code, the Criteria should be an internal implmentation detail of the DAO, and shouldn't be visible to the calling methods.