# Filter subentities of entity

Tags: java, spring-data, criteria

Let's say I have user and each user has list of orders:

*Setters, getters, ids are skipped*

```
@Entity
class Order {
    private int price;
}


@Entity
class User {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(..)
    private Set<Order> orders;
}
```

With java criteria API I want to create query to load all Users that have orders with price > 100 and fetch Orders with this price.

If I create query like

```
criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(root.join("orders").get("price"), 100);
```

I'll get right users but with *all* orders. Can I fetch only required orders?

Answer (score 0):

You can use detached query criteria approach:

```
DetachedCriteria maxQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Order.class);
maxQuery.add(Restrictions.gt("price", 100));
```

and add the maxQuery to your original User.class query as follows:

```
userQuery.add(Property.forName("orders").eq(maxQuery));
```

For reference [when to use detached criteria in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925948/when-to-use-detached-criteria-in-hibernate)